# geom_bar invalid y.axis values R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe:

```
> str(drivePerTaskMelted)
'data.frame':   10508 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ CSS_WEEK_END_DATE: Date, format: "2012-01-13" "2012-01-20" "2012-01-27" "2012-02-03" ...
 $ patch            : Factor w/ 71 levels "BV","BVG","BVH",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Drive.Per.Task   : num  28 28.8 28.2 28.1 27.9 26.4 26.6 26.6 26.6 26.7 ...
 $ Months           : chr  "January" "January" "January" "February" ...
```

I am trying to draw a bar plot:

```
ggplot(drivePerTaskMelted[patch==c("BVG1","BVG2","BVG3","BVG4"),],
aes(x=patch, y=Drive.Per.Task,fill=patch)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
geom_text(aes(label = max(Drive.Per.Task, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

this draws the following plot:

[image]

I have used the `stat="identity"` But it still not using the y.values as is. y values are like 28, 28.2 etc. Additionally I am trying to label the maximum y.axis value on top of each bar. But it is showing 35.2 in a weird way at the bottom.

For example: Summary for BVG1 is:

```
> summary(drivePerTaskMelted[patch=="BVG1",])
 CSS_WEEK_END_DATE        patch     Drive.Per.Task     Months         
 Min.   :2012-01-13   BVG1   :148   Min.   :22.60   Length:148        
 1st Qu.:2012-09-26   BV     :  0   1st Qu.:28.38   Class :character  
 Median :2013-06-10   BVG    :  0   Median :30.20   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :2013-06-10   BVH    :  0   Mean   :30.08                     
 3rd Qu.:2014-02-22   BVG2   :  0   3rd Qu.:31.70                     
 Max.   :2014-11-07   BVG3   :  0   Max.   :35.90                     
                      (Other):  0
```

thanks here,

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to produce what you want, but it's impossible to test without your dataset. This creates a barplot of the mean `Drive.Per.Task` for each `patch`, and displays the maximum `Drive.Per.Task` above the bar.

```
# not tested
library(ggplot2)
labs <- function(x) data.frame(y=mean(x)+0.2,label=round(max(x),2))
ggplot(drivePerTaskMelted[patch %in% c("BVG1","BVG2","BVG3","BVG4"),],
       aes(x=patch, y=Drive.Per.Task,fill=patch)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="bar")+
  stat_summary(fun.data=labs,geom="text")
```

This assumes there is a vector `patch` defined outside of the data frame `drivePerTaskMelted`.

Also, note that `patch %in% c("BVG1","BVG2","BVG3","BVG4")` is *not the same* as `patch==c("BVG1","BVG2","BVG3","BVG4")`. The former is the correct way to extract the rows containing BVG1 - 4.

Here is a working demo using the built-in `mtcars` dataset.

```
# use built-in mtcars dataset for demonstration
df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)   # number of cylinders to factor

labs <- function(x) data.frame(y=mean(x)+0.2,label=round(max(x),2))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=cyl,y=wt,fill=cyl))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="bar")+
  stat_summary(fun.data=labs,geom="text")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there are many CSS_WEEK_END_DATE columns and you are seeing the sum of all. Are you looking at a specific date? Can you run the following and see if the bars/values are better now?

```
ggplot(drivePerTaskMelted[patch %in% c("BVG1","BVG2","BVG3","BVG4"),],aes(x=patch, y=Drive.Per.Task,fill=patch)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
geom_text(aes(label = max(Drive.Per.Task, na.rm = TRUE)))+
facet_wrap(~ CSS_WEEK_END_DATE))
```

Comment: I am not looking at a specific date. All I want is to show The exact values on y axis for all these patches i.e. BVG1, BVG2,BVG3,BVG4. Facet_wrap indeed shows the correct y.axis values but draws the bar plot for every date in CSS_WEEK_END_DATE.

Comment: your code produced this: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx3tk.png

Comment: Ok, since there are many dates there, I don't know how to make a bar plot, unless you sum/average/etc across all dates. Last idea, maybe something like this:  ggplot(drivePerTaskMelted[patch %in% c("BVG1","BVG2","BVG3","BVG4"),],
       aes(x=patch, y=Drive.Per.Task,color=patch)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_jitter()

Comment: Could you give an example of plotting an average across these 4 patches?

Comment: I am mostly using another library too (data.table) which really fast. Here it is:

library(data.table)
drivePerTaskMelted=as.data.table(drivePerTaskMelted)
drivePerTaskMelted.mean<-drivePerTaskMelted[,lapply(.SD,mean),by='patch',.SDcols='Drive.Per.Task']

ggplot(drivePerTaskMelted.mean[patch %in% c("BVG1","BVG2","BVG3","BVG4"),],aes(x=patch, y=Drive.Per.Task,fill=patch)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = max(Drive.Per.Task, na.rm = TRUE)))

Comment: Thanks for your help. The last thing... What does this mean? lapply(.SD,mean). I know you applied the lapply to calculate the mean per patch but what is .SD? I was wondering if I could calculate something like: mean+sd of the Drive.Per.Task to accommodate the variation over period?